# Html customizing select tag using CSS and Divs

Tags: html, css, select, drop-down-menu

Ok so i'm trying to create a custom html select box using css and divs spans.
I don't see any mistakes on it but have no idea why it's not working

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bdq1yk8r/)

```
<div class="ik_select episodes_list_selectbox ik_select_autowidth" style="position: relative; width: 258px;">
<div class="ik_select_link episodes_list_selectbox-link">
<div class="ik_select_link_text">active opt 4</div></div>
<div class="ik_select_dropdown episodes_list_selectbox-dd" style="position: absolute; z-index: 9998; width: 100%; display: none;">
<div class="ik_select_list" style="position: relative;">
<div class="ik_select_filter_wrap">
```

Comment: Are you working this for a website or an app? Normally select statement doesn't go like this!

Answer (score 0):

A basic select statement goes like this:

```
<select class="yourStyle">
    <option>option_1</option>
    <option>option_2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per select part is considered, you should use inbuilt select-option pair to work perfectly. If you insist to use DIV's for that purpose, then you must have to use some JavaScript over there to make it work.

As per my opinion you should customize select-option to work for you like this,

```css
.custom-select {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
}

/* This is the native select, we're making everything but the text invisible so
 * we can see the button styles in the wrapper */
.custom-select select {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 outline: none;
 padding: .6em .8em .5em .8em;

 /* Prefixed box-sizing rules necessary for older browsers */
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;

 /* Font size must be 16px to prevent iOS page zoom on focus */
 font-size: 16px;
}


/* Custom arrow sits on top of the select - could be an image, SVG, icon font,
 * etc. or the arrow could just baked into the bg image on the select. */
.custom-select::after {
 content: " ";
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 right: 1em;
 z-index: 2;
 /* These hacks make the select behind the arrow clickable in some browsers */
 pointer-events: none;
 display: none;
}
@supports ( -webkit-appearance: none ) or ( appearance: none )
 /* Firefox <= 34 has a false positive on @supports( -moz-appearance: none )
  * @supports ( mask-type: alpha ) is Firefox 35+
  */
 or ( ( -moz-appearance: none ) and ( mask-type: alpha ) ) {
 
 /* Show custom arrow */
 .custom-select::after {
  display: block;
 }

 /* Remove select styling */
 .custom-select select {
  padding-right: 2em; /* Match-01 */
  /* inside @supports so that iOS <= 8 display the native arrow */
  background: none; /* Match-04 */
  /* inside @supports so that Android <= 4.3 display the native arrow */
  border: 1px solid transparent; /* Match-05 */

  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
 }
 .custom-select select:focus {
  border-color: #aaa; /* Match-03 */
 }
}
.custom-select {
 border: 3px solid #303840;
 background: #56B4F9;
}

.custom-select::after {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 4px solid transparent;
 border-right: 4px solid transparent;
 border-top: 7px solid #303840;
 margin-top: -3px;
}

.custom-select select {
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Avenir, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 letter-spacing: 0px;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #303840;
 line-height: 1.5;
 cursor: pointer;
}


/* Focus style */

.custom-select select:focus {
 outline: none;
 box-shadow: none;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
}


/* Set options to normal weight */

.custom-select option {
 font-weight: bold;
 background: #fff;
 box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<span>Choose an effect:</span>
<div class="custom-select">
  <select name="select" id="select-effect">
<option value="1" selected>Triple Swoosh</option> 
<option value="2">Simple</option>
<option value="3">Duo Move</option>
<option value="4">Content Move</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the nature of your project, there is multiple reasons why using `div` elements to stylize a `select` might be a bad idea. To name a few:

- You will not benefit from the native mobile browser UI support.
- You might also suffer side effects to accessibility and usability.

If you want full details there is a very good article on the topic [here](http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/04/08/css-alternative-select/).

If you still think you need this, I doubt that trying to repair the JSFiddle you provided will provide a good return on investment. You need a lot more than this to get a good select alternative (including some non-negligible JavaScript). What I would suggest is to look into popular existing solutions to get there instead, such as:

1. Select2: https://select2.github.io/examples.html
2. bootstrap-select: http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/
3. Selectize.js: http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/
4. Etc.